# Pivot Macro not functioning

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I made a macro (seen below) that was working previously and has stopped working all of a sudden. It was creating a pivot table and now it has stopped doing that. I don't see any changes made that would cause this. When I debug it there are no erros and when I look through the Locals I see that it is capturing the rows and columns. What could be causing the macro to stop creating the pivot table?

```
Dim PRange As Range 'Source data range
Dim lastRow As Long 'Last Row of Report even if it changes
Dim lastCol As Long 'Last Column of Report even if it changes
Dim DSheet As Worksheet 'Claiming "Report" sheet as data sheet
Dim PSheet As Worksheet 'Claiming what is pivot sheet for this macro
Dim ptType As String

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Reclass").Delete
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Reclass"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Reclass")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Report")
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reclass").Tab
        .Color = 8988
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

'Defining Data Range. Taking the first cell of the data table and select uptp the last row and then up to the last column
    lastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = DSheet.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(7, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol)

'Create pivot cache. Defines Pivot Cache by using Data source and defines the cell address in the new worksheet to insert pivot table
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="ReclassPush")

'Insert Pivot Table
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTables(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="ReclassPush")

'Putting Row Fields in
    With ActiveSheet.pivotTable("ReclassPush").PivotFields("PO Requestor")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reason")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Orginal PO Requester"

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("NonReclass").PivotFields("PO Requestor")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

'Putting Values Field in
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "ReclassPush").PivotFields("Func Currency Amt"), "Sum of Func Currency Amt", _
        xlSum


'Putting Filter Fields in: Adds reclass filter to pivot table and shows only PO Requestors who needed their JE to be Reclassed
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reclass Flag")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reclass Flag"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reclass Flag"). _
        CurrentPage = "Y"
```

Edited code referring to comment:

```
Option Explicit
'Macro is makes list of users who submitted reclasses through the adjustments tool as well well as the reason why for the reclass

Sub MakeAPivotTable()

Dim pt As pivotTable 'Creates pivot table
Dim pc As PivotCache 'Pivot Cache
Dim pf As PivotField 'Pivot Field
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim PRange As Range 'Source data range
Dim lastRow As Long 'Last Row of Report even if it changes
Dim lastCol As Long 'Last Column of Report even if it changes
Dim DSheet As Worksheet 'Claiming "Report" sheet as data sheet
Dim PSheet As Worksheet 'Claiming what is pivot sheet for this macro
Dim ptType As String

'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Reclass").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Reclass"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Reclass")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Report")
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reclass").Tab
        .Color = 8988
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

'Defining Data Range. Taking the first cell of the data table and select uptp the last row and then up to the last column
    lastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = DSheet.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(7, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol)

'Create pivot cache. Defines Pivot Cache by using Data source and defines the cell address in the new worksheet to insert pivot table
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="ReclassPush")

'Insert Pivot Table
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="ReclassPush")

'Putting Row Fields in
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("PO Requestor")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reason")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Orginal PO Requester"

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("NonReclass").PivotFields("PO Requestor")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

'Putting Values Field in
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "ReclassPush").PivotFields("Func Currency Amt"), "Sum of Func Currency Amt", _
        xlSum


'Putting Filter Fields in: Adds reclass filter to pivot table and shows only PO Requestors who needed their JE to be Reclassed
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reclass Flag")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reclass Flag"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("Reclass Flag"). _
        CurrentPage = "Y"



    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").ColumnGrand = False
    Range("B4").Select

    'Tabular Form
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ReclassPush").PivotFields("PO Requestor").LayoutForm _
        = xlTabular

      Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
End Sub
```

Comment: The `On Error Resume Next` statement is masking the problem. Put a `On Error Goto 0` after the `Worksheets("Reclass").Delete` line, then rerun the code and tell us the error.

Comment: Ok I did that and Debugged it and still no error popped up

Comment: Any suggestions @jeffreyweir ?

Comment: Can you repost your edited code, and include the entire sub (unless it's like really, really long)?

Comment: It gets sloppy towards the end because I recorded some things. There's the edited version though

Comment: Okay. I'm off for a walk for the rest of the day. Might get a chance to take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @jeffreyweir get a chance to look at it? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you run the code. i.e are you saying that you run the code, it runs without error, but a PivotTable never gets created?

Comment: It seems to me the line `Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="ReclassPush")` is wrong. Should just be `Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)` because you create a PivotTable on the next line. But it doesn't sound correct that you are running the code as posted and not getting an error.